# Django models caching

Tags: python, django, django-models

In models.py I have models Order and Item, Item containing price and weight:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(u'Name', max_length=255) 
    article = models.CharField(u'Article',  max_length=255) 
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(u'Price') 
    weight = models.PositiveIntegerField(u'weight', blank=True, null=True, default=None)

class Order(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, verbose_name=u'Item')
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(u'Count') 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=u'User')

    def sum(self):
        return self.count*self.item.price

    def weight(self):
        return self.count*self.item.weight
```

In views.py I select my orders:

```
@render_to('app/purchase_view.html')
def purchase_view(request):
        myorders = Order.objects.select_related().filter(user=request.user).all()

        context.update({
            'myorders':myorders,
        })
```

And in template:

```
        {% for myorder in myorders %}

                <td>{{ myorder.item.article }}</td>
                <td style="text-align:left;"><a href="#">{{ myorder.item.name }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ myorder.item.price }}</td>
                <td>{{ myorder.count }}</td>
                <td>{{ myorder.sum }}</td>
                <td>{{ myorder.weight }}</td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

so, django generates for each parameter: myorder.sum, myorder.weight - similar queries. Is there something for cache in Order model sum and weight.

Comment: There are many easy ways of doing this caching, but no reason to. All you'd be caching is the result of an integer multiplication; you won't be saving a DB roundtrip since you already access `order.item` in the template, and you're using select_related anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are actually asking, but [quersets in django are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy). This means that django doesn't actually execute the query until the [queryset is evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated).

This might be what you are seeing when you say its cached.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think Django is doing queries to get order.price and order.weight? It isn't. It's doing a single query, to get the order and its associated item (because you used select_related). Everything after that is simply operations on data it already has.

Comment: select_related caches myorder.item.article, myorder.item.name, but for myorder.price, myorder.weight django do two queries

Comment: No it doesn't. Those methods refer to `self.item`, which is already cached. (I presume you mean `myorder.sum`, not price.)